# Time taken by 10000 API calls in too long

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, waitgroup

I am learning and trying the `WaitGroup` functionality in Golang. Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "atomic"
    "http"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func makeRequest(n int) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    count := atomic.Int32{}
    wg.Add(n)
    s := time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
        go myGoRoutine(&wg, &count)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    log.Printf("Time Elapsed: %v for %d iterations", time.Since(s), n)
}

func myGoRoutine(wg *sync.WaitGroup, count *atomic.Int32) {
    defer wg.Done()
    _, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %v", err.Error())
    }
    count.Add(1)
}
func main() {
    cases := []int{1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}
    for _, c := range cases {
        makeRequest(c)
    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
2023/12/28 07:31:34 Time Elapsed: 936.169917ms for 1 iterations
2023/12/28 07:31:34 Time Elapsed: 16.452041ms for 10 iterations
2023/12/28 07:31:34 Time Elapsed: 37.336667ms for 100 iterations
2023/12/28 07:31:36 Time Elapsed: 2.037294792s for 1000 iterations
2023/12/28 07:32:23 Time Elapsed: 47.1717935s for 10000 iterations
```

Since all API calls are happening concurrently, I expect all 5 cases to take similar if not the same amount of time. This is indeed true for the first 3 cases but then it takes 2s for 1000 and over 45s for 10000 API calls.

My understanding of `WaitGroup` in Golang is barely a couple of days old. Its likely that I am making a mistake in the code or my fundamental understanding is incorrect. Either way, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "all 5 cases to take similar if not the same amount of time" no reason to think the receiving end of those requests is going to think those are all the same

Comment: I have tried with other dummy APIs too. It behaves similarly.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

- We need to check the overhead of Goroutine by using Benchmark test if needed.
- Goroutine itself is efficient when doing multiple high load tasks in parallel. But if the load is too tiny, then it can be better to do them in serial.
- Your code is not proper to test Goroutine performance because Calling API multiple times can make **queueing at the backend server**.

## In detail

### Go routine test with low load task

- You can see go routine has worse-performance with low load tasks than just calling a function

```golang
func BenchmarkTest_makeRequest(b *testing.B) {
    tests := []struct {
        makeRequest func(n int)
    }{
        {
            makeRequest: makeRequestWithGoRoutine,
        },

        {
            makeRequest: makeRequestWithoutGoRoutine,
        },

        {
            makeRequest: makeRequestWithoutFunctionCall,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        b.Run("test", func(b *testing.B) {
            tt.makeRequest(b.N)
        })
    }
}
```

```
BenchmarkTest_makeRequest/test-12                5522967               206.9 ns/op
BenchmarkTest_makeRequest/test#01-12            79312916                15.42 ns/op
BenchmarkTest_makeRequest/test#02-12            163376266                6.478 ns/op
```

### Go routine test with high load task

- You can see go routine has higher-performance with high load tasks than just calling a function
- For simulating the high load, I just added `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)`.

```golang
func BenchmarkTest_makeRequestWithHighLoad(b *testing.B) {
    tests := []struct {
        makeRequest func(n int)
    }{
        {
            makeRequest: makeRequestWithGoRoutine,
        },

        {
            makeRequest: makeRequestWithoutGoRoutine,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        b.Run("test", func(b *testing.B) {
            tt.makeRequest(b.N)
        })
    }
}
```

```
BenchmarkTest_makeRequestWithHighLoad/test-12            2819386               409.7 ns/op
BenchmarkTest_makeRequestWithHighLoad/test#01-12             100          10787388 ns/op
```

### What overhead are in Goroutine and how can we handle it?

- The spawning Goroutine can make some overhead.

  - Goroutine also has its own stack
  - If there are multiple Goroutines, it needs to do scheduling, GC and etc.
  - Surely, it is cheaper than thread.
  - ref. https://blog.nindalf.com/posts/how-goroutines-work/
- It can be helpful that you utilize Goroutine pool (Worker pool, aka Thread pool) rather than making a Goroutine each time

  - ref. https://medium.com/code-chasm/go-concurrency-pattern-worker-pool-a437117025b1

### The rest of the codes

```golang
func myGoRoutine(wg *sync.WaitGroup, count *int32) {
    defer wg.Done()
    atomic.AddInt32(count, 1)
}
func myGoRoutineWithHighLoad(wg *sync.WaitGroup, count *int32) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    atomic.AddInt32(count, 1)
}

func makeRequestWithGoRoutine(n int) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    var count int32
    wg.Add(n)
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
//      go myGoRoutine(&wg, &count)
        go myGoRoutineWithHighLoad(&wg, &count)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func makeRequestWithoutGoRoutine(n int) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    var count int32
    wg.Add(n)
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
//      myGoRoutine(&wg, &count)
        myGoRoutineWithHighLoad(&wg, &count)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func makeRequestWithoutFunctionCall(n int) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    var count int32
    wg.Add(n)
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
        count++
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It was really helpful. Is there anyway to figure out that it is the other API server that is delaying the responses if the calls go above 1000? Perhaps it is better to cap the concurrent goroutines using a semaphore.

Comment: @muezz How about using `context` in `request`, like this?
Then you get the timeout from response if the delay of the backend server is beyond `context`'s timeout.
ref. https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-context-with-timeout-example.html

Comment: For checking the delay of the backend server, I think we can measure the latency of response as you did and keep monitoring it.